# how to order in while loop?

Tags: php, algorithm, loops, while-loop

I want to get  the count of characters from the following words in the string. For example, if my input is `I am John` then the output must be like this:

```
9 // count of 'I am John'
4 // count of 'I am'
1 // count of 'I'
```

I use the code like this in PHP for this process:

```
$string = 'I am John';
$words = explode(' ',$string);
$count_words = count($words);

$i =0;
while ($i<$count_words){
    if($i==0) {
    $words_length[$i] = strlen($words[$i]);
    } else {
    $words_length[$i] = strlen($words[$i])+1+$words_length[$i-1];
    }
    echo $words_length[$i]."<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

But it return the output like this:

```
1
4
9
```

Why ? Where is my error ? How can I change the ordering ?
 What does my code must be like ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to have the output in reverse order use [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php):

```
print_r(array_reverse($words_length));
```

Answer (score 2):

The quickest fix is to add `print_r(array_reverse($words_length));` after the loop

Comment: but it returns `Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 1 [2] => 4 ) ` :(

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're looping through the words left to right. You can't output the full length right to left, because each one depends on the words to it's left.

You could take the `echo` out of the loop, and print the values after all have been calculated.

```
$string = 'I am John';
$words = explode(' ',$string);
$count_words = count($words);

$i =0;
while ($i<$count_words){
    if($i==0) {
        $words_length[$i] = strlen($words[$i]);
    } else {
        $words_length[$i] = strlen($words[$i])+1+$words_length[$i-1];
    }
    $i++;
}

print implode('<br />', array_reverse($words_length));
```

Comment: now, I want to do the processes in these digits (9,4,1). so ,it must be in array. how can I do this ?

Comment: @John After the loop, you have an `array(1, 4, 9)`. You can reverse that with `array_reverse($words_length)` which will be `array(9,4,1)`

Comment: Sorry, I now mentioned that, I need array_reverse() function. So I don't choose your answer as acceptable (

Comment: @John Why don't you want to use `array_reverse()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use foreach and array_reverse to get the array values:

```
foreach(array_reverse($words_length) as $val){
echo $val;
}
```